# How to load the child class in tabview in android

Tags: android, tabbar

currently am working with TabActivity in android,i have 4 tabs and in the 4'th tab the main class is calss A,and other class are class B,class c,my questions is when i click on my 4'th tab i want to laod the Class c in the tabview.is it possible.please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can,

```
   TabHost mTabHost;
   TabHost.TabSpec spec; // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
   Intent intent; // Reusable Intent for each tab
```

Now add your class,

```
   mTabHost = getTabHost();
   // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, A.class);
    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = mTabHost
            .newTabSpec("Class A")
            .setIndicator("Class A", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.home_selector))
            .setContent(intent);
    mTabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Same way you can add another classes, here I used drawble background

Comment: i have 3 classs ,class A,class B,class C.normally the tabbar loads the class A,but when some conditions are satisfied it must load the class c in the same tab where the class A is previously loaded.

Comment: You can handle this by flag value, if true than Class C else Class A